# I want to get status of all my friend in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get the status of my friend i-e (pending or he accepted my request or he blocks me)
for this
I get all my friend except login one and get their respective status

```
$user=User::with(["friendships"])->where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

my model

```
function friendships() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Friendship','first_user','id');
}
```

my friendship database table is like that

```
id  first_user  second_user   status
```

where the first user is the one who sends the request and the second_user is the one who receives the request, where the status is either pending, accepted, or blocked  .so how could I load all my friends and check the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so firstly you say "I" want to get all my friendships. So the query would need to change for this. The following query that you have right now is as follows:

```
$user=User::with(["friendships"])->where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

This is getting ALL users that are NOT the currently logged in user. What you want is to get your currently authenticated user and load in the friendships relationship to do this you can do as follows:

```
$user = User::with('friendships')->find(Auth::id());
```

So to break this down with `->find(Auth::id())` you are getting the user with that id. Second you are returning only one user not a collection of users which you would get by using `->get()`.

Then you could do something like this in a blade file.

```
@foreach($user->friendships as $friendship)
    $friendship->status
@endforeach
```

Edit:

So my misunderstanding of the situation, for getting all users and then attaching a status of a friendship with the current user if they had one could look like

```
$authenticatedUserId = Auth::id();

$users = User::with([
    'friendships' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('first_user', $authenticatedUserId);
    }
]);
```

And then display this like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->friendships->count() > 0)
        $user->friendships->first()->status // A user should only have one friendship with another user
    @else
        // No friendship so add a button to add a friendship
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Note this would only include send friend requests, not any sent to you by another user. But they would be in the list of users so you could end up with duplicate friend requests you would need to filter these out in this case. Checkout the documentation for more help on doing this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: ok but i also want to load other user so i can send request to him

Comment: Made some changes and attached docs for any more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
$userID = Auth::id();

$user=User::whereDoesntHave('friendships',  function($q){
     $q->where('first_user', '=', $userID );
})->get();
```

Comment: This would show users that has no relationship with the current user, but a relationship would have been formed with a status of "pending" for example if one had been sent but not accepted.

Comment: Actually he does not want to see the status of Login User.