# I want to get all users and friend status in laravel

Tags: laravel

First of all I want to popup all the users from user table except me i-e login user and secondly I also want to get friendship status if I send request to any user status should be pending if other user accept my request then status should be friend and if I didn't send any request then the status should be null.
For that purpose I have two tables users and friendship ,where user table is default laravel table while friendship table is like that

```
id   first_user   second_user    status
```

first user is the one who send request while second user is one who receive request and status is either pending or accepted.
for that currently I create that logic

```
$user=DB::table('users')
         ->leftJoin('friendships','friendships.second_user','=','users.id')
         ->where('users.id','!=',Auth::user()->id)
         ->where('friendships.first_user',Auth::user()->id)  
         ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','friendships.status')
         ->get();
```

but this code return me only those user to which I send request, but I also want to get those users to which I didn't send any request so I can send request to him.

my view is similar to facebook where I can see all users

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Comment: Is the answer not on your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452358/i-want-to-get-status-of-all-my-friend-in-laravel/67452437#67452437

Comment: sorry i didn't check your updated answer and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in `->where('friendships.first_user', Auth::user()->id)`.

Try this instead

```php
$user = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('friendships', 'friendships.second_user', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::id())
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->orWhere('friendships.first_user', Auth::id())
                     ->orWhereNull('friendships.first_user');
    })
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'friendships.status')
    ->get();
```